# List comprehension in python error?

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x

I want to get the result of nmcli (linux) in a 3D list in python.

The sample output of `nmcli device show` is

> GENERAL.DEVICE:                         wlan0
>   GENERAL.TYPE:                           wifi
>   GENERAL.HWADDR:                         :::::
>   GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
>   GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
>   GENERAL.CONNECTION:
>   GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/2
>   IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.1.106/16
>   IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.1.1
>   IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.1.1, mt = 600
>   IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 600
>   IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.1.1
>   IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         :::::::/
>   IP6.ADDRESS[2]:                         :::::/
>   IP6.GATEWAY:                            :::::
>   IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = :::::/, nh = ::, mt = 600
>   IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ::/0, nh = fe80::30ae:bfff:fe20:64d, mt = 600
>   IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = ::/, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
>   IP6.ROUTE[4]:                           dst = ::/, nh = ::, mt = 256
>   IP6.ROUTE[5]:                           dst = ::/, nh = ::, mt = 600
>   IP6.DNS[1]:                             :::::
>   IP6.DNS[2]:                             :::::::
>
> GENERAL.DEVICE:                         eth0
>   GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
>   GENERAL.HWADDR:                         :::::
>   GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
>   GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
>   GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
>   GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
>   WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
>
> GENERAL.DEVICE:                         lo
>   GENERAL.TYPE:                           loopback
>   GENERAL.HWADDR:                         00:00:00:00:00:00
>   GENERAL.MTU:                            65536
>   GENERAL.STATE:                          10 (unmanaged)
>   GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
>   GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
>   IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         127.0.0.1/8
>   IP4.GATEWAY:                            --
>   IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         ::1/128
>   IP6.GATEWAY:                            --

As you can see there are three interfaces : wlan0 , eth0 and lo.
I want a list of columns in a list of rows in a list of interfaces (3D).

I used subprocess to get the result

```
r1 = subprocess.run(['nmcli', 'device', 'show'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
r2 = [y.split() for y in [z.split('\n') for z in r1.split('\n\n')]]
```

But I get the following error

```
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <listcom>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'
```

Any suggestions?

PS: I ran that on python 3.6.3 shell

Comment: I suggest you break your code into smaller pieces. For example assign `[z.split('\n') for z in r1.split('\n\n')]` to its own variable so that you can more easily check its value. Better yet, assign `r1.split('\n\n')]` to a variable. If you do this, you can add `print()` statements to verify that the values are what you are expect and modify your code when they are not.

Comment: I was sticking to this method since I wanted to make a one liner. '@Mark Ransom' have already provided the correct answer. Thank you.

Comment: One liners are difficult to read and even more difficult to debug.

Comment: I agree. But sometimes one liners are useful to reduce the overall complexity.

Comment: the fact that you are unable to debug code easily is a sign of complexity. My original suggestion was intended to help you debug and fix your code. Once you have a correct solution you can reactor to your heart's content.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `[z.split('\n') for z in r1.split('\n\n')]` is a list of lists, so when you iterate over it you are trying to split a list instead of a string. The error is in `y.split()`.

I think what you want is:

```
r2 = [[y.split() for y in z.split('\n')] for z in r1.split('\n\n')]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.